# Proving this set is not a differentiable manifold

Tags: analysis, manifolds

Let $A = \{ (2n\pi, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} ; \,  n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. How can I prove that this set is not a differentiable manifold?

My attempt was trying to prove it by contradiction. Suppose that exists a chart $\varphi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow A \cap V$, where $V$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $U$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

By the discrete topology, $A \cap V$ is both open an closed. Since $\varphi$ in particular is a homeomorphism, we should have that $\varphi^{-1}(A \cap V)$ is closed. However, $U$ is open.

Therefore, by contradiction, $\varphi$ does not exist.

Is this proof correct?

Thank you!

Comment: What has your question to do with discrete topology?

Comment: Isn't the topology of $A$ the discrete topology?

Comment: It is a differentiable manifold. In particular, it is a zero-dimensional manifold.

Comment: @Mathemagician Yes. But then it would have been more natural that you would have written something like “Since the topology of $A$ is the discrete topology, $A\cap V$ is both open and closed.”